# Different results on SonarQube analysis in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I've got an issue linked to the sonar analysis via the sonar eclipse plugin.

This is my scenario:

- A dedicated SVN server containing the projects
- A dedicated SonarQube server for sonar analysis
- Several Win7 workstations using the same eclipse release (Eclipse + plugin versions centrally deployed in the company). Eclipse version: 4.4.1, Sonar-Eclipse plugin version: 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE, SonarQube server version: 5.1

We are regularly running analysis for the base branches via Jenkins. When reintegrating and developing a branch we are using the Sonar Eclipse plugin to check against the base version. We have detected a strange behaviour from the local analysis via Eclipse.

We used several workstations and checked out the same project having the same SVN revision. We configured the Workstations identically (same project associations, same sonar server address, etc.). When the analysis finished often the workstations had different results for the analysis (about 1 to 15 percent of the issues). Has anyone experienced this behaviour or found a solution for it?

edit:
Well our analysis of a given project via Jenkins gives this Result:

- 39 Blocker
- 1943 Critical
- 36840 Major
- 6150 Minor
- 675 Info

For Example one client using the exakt same revision for eclipse analysis has:

- 39 Blocker
- 1957 Critical
- 36524 Major
- 6124 Minor
- 680 Info

Another:

- 39 Blocker
- 1912 Critical
- 36248 Major
- 7865 Minor
- 634 Info

The problems are increasing if not showing all issues but new issues. As hotfix we did set the "last analysis date" parameter to "0" on the configuration file. That made the results more alike but they still have a given delta on the same sources.

Comment: If you don't give more detail about the differences, it's will be hard to help you.

Comment: I've got edited the message above for an sample of the alternations. The clients have all the same configuration and even using the same config file on eclipse doesn't fix this.

Comment: I know this can be tedious, but we won't be able to help as long as we don't have more details about the differences. The issue severity does not help to know which rules are implied. I suggest you to find a file for which there's a difference, find the issues that are missing on one side, see if they all relate to the same rule or not, and from this point we might have more clues about what's happening.

Comment: I'll add a sample on monday when I return to work... But if I remember right it occurs on several rules...

Comment: I hope this will be fixed after switching to 5.2... I'll report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not able to reconstruct on purpose. I think meanwhile the error was in front of the computer.

We had in some cases issues with the project association, so I think that was the reason.

CLOSED.